# Simple SQL test adding two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, web

Been having trouble with question 13, how do I get the two totals to add together after I have run the Query?
[Picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ZZo.png)

Comment: you can't even be bothered typing the question?

Comment: I voted to close . . . you can't even be bothered to explain what Question 13 is.

Comment: Have you even tried to implement a query yourself? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: well.. last time i checked plain textboxes dont allow you to insert tables. So i thought it would be nice to just have it all in the one picture, if you would like it though I'll type it here for you so you can read it without having to go to the image:

Comment: 13.  What is the total number of deaths caused by bushfire or flood?

also the query i tried is in the picture, thats where I got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try removing "`GROUP BY Cause`"...?